# 404 error with $http.post when content-type is set to application/json

Tags: json, angularjs, http, cors, content-type

I'm trying to authenticate with an API that takes a json object like this:

```
$scope.loginAuth = function() {
        var params = {UserId: $scope.userName, Password: $scope.password};
        $http({
            url:"https://www.apiurl.com:8086/api/login",
            headers:{'Content-Type': 'application/json'},
            method: "post",
            data: params
        }).success(function(data,status,headers,config){
            console.log(data);

        }).error(function(data,status,headers,config){
            console.log(data,status,headers,config);
        })
```

I'm receiving this error:

```
OPTIONS https://www.apiurl.com:8086/api/login 404 (Not Found)         angular.js:8407
XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://www.apiurl.com:8086/api/login.  Invalid HTTP status code 404
```

If I change the content-type to : `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` I get a 401 not authorized error, so it's just not reading the json object properly.

I've setup CORS on the IIS server that hosts the api, but I am still not having any luck.  Any thoughts or ideas would be appreciated!

---

UPDATE: Web.config file on API site

```
<system.webServer>
<httpProtocol>
<customHeaders>
<add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />
<add name="Access-Control-Allow-Credentials" value="true" />
<add name="Access-Control-Allow-Methods" value="GET,POST,PUT,OPTIONS" />
<add name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" value="Origin,Content-Type,Accept,Authorization,X-Ellucian-Media-Type" />
</customHeaders> 
</httpProtocol>
```

Also worth noting, when using the chrome extension "Postman" (rest api testing app), I can make the request fine with the application/json header and I get the valid token.  It's only when I'm making the request through angular that I get the 404.

Comment: Is this CORS with ASPNET? or something else?

Comment: Does your backend support `application/json`? Other point: your error says `OPTIONS https://www.apiurl.com:8086/api//login` (see the double `/` before login) - is that just a typo in your question or are you requesting the wrong url?

Comment: Sorry that was a typo in the question Dominik.

CORS is configured on IIS, although I may not have done it properly I guess.  I will post the web.config tomorrow as well.

Comment: updated question with web.config.  Also yes the api supports application/json.  The request works fine in postman chrome extension.